# Get the method name of the callee in v8

Tags: v8

Since nodejs >= 10 FunctionCallbackInfo::Callee has been deprecated (https://github.com/nodejs/nan/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). I need to update a c++ code that uses v8, where the method name being called was used. How to get that now?

It is recommemded to use `info.Data()` instead. But I don't follow how to get the methods name from that. I guess it goes something like this:

```
void GetData(IN const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& info)
{
    v8::Local<v8::Function> data = v8::Local<v8::Function>::Cast(info.Data());

    ....

}
```

How do I get the methods name from `data`? From the documentation, looks like it cannot be done any longer (https://github.com/nodejs/nan/blob/master/doc/methods.md):

> Note: FunctionCallbackInfo::Callee is removed in Node.js after 10.0.0 because it is was deprecated in V8. Consider using info.Data() to pass any information you need.

So, if no extra information is supplied, there is no way to get the name of the callee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
    v8::Local<v8::Function> out;
    out = v8::Local<v8::Function>::Cast(info.Data());
    v8::String::Utf8Value callee(out->GetName()->ToString());
```